# Is there an item that gives a PC regeneration?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

I do not have, nor know where to find, a list of all magical items in 5e. I know the list is fairly short comparatively to other D&D games.

I'd like to know if there's a weapon, or item, that allows a PC to regain HP (that isn't a one-time use item), even for short bursts.

Comment: What kind of regeneration? Are you looking for any item that allows a PC to regain HP? Is it specific to worn equipment and the like?

Comment: Yes i was looking for item/s that could make a PC regain HP.

Comment: Are you asking as a player or the DM?

Comment: I was asking as the player

Answer (score 36, accepted):

> ### Ring of Regeneration
>
> Ring, Major, Very Rare (Requires Attunement)
>   While wearing this ring, you regain 1d6 hit points every 10 minutes, provided that you have at least 1 hit point. If you lose a body part, the ring causes the missing part to regrow and return to full functionality after 1d6+1 days if you have at least 1 hit point the whole time.
>
> *Source: Dungeon Master's Guide, page 191*

---

> ### Ioun Stone, Regeneration
>
> Wondrous Item, Major, Legendary (Requires Attunement)
>   [Removed unrelated effects.]
>
> You regain 15 hit points at the end of each hour this pearly white spindle orbits your head, provided that you have at least 1 hit point.
>
> *Source: Dungeon Master's Guide, page 176*

---

> ### Hand of Vecna
>
> Wondrous Item, Artifact (Requires Attunement)
>   [Remove full item description.]
>   Properties of the Eye and Hand. If you are attuned to both the hand and eye, you gain the following additional benefits:
>
> - [Removed unrelated effects.]
> - If you start your turn with at least 1 hit point, you regain 1d10 hit points.
>
> *Source: Dungeon Master's Guide, page 224*

---

### Regeneration Ability

The above items give you something weaker than monster regeneration (which can be upwards of 10 HP every round, usually 20). As far as I'm aware, there's no official item which gives Regeneration of that grade to anyone. The closest you'll get is 1d10 HP every round with the Hand of Vecna, and only if you attune the Eye of Vecna as well. Both of which are Artifacts of the highest rarity, body parts of one of D&D's most-famous Liches.

Comment: *If you lose a body part, the ring causes the missing part to regrow * what part is the "lost part" if the ring-wearing hand gets chopped off? Cloning anybody? Does this warrant its own question? :D

Comment: @iraserd https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/37288/cut-off-hand-with-ring-of-regeneration-on-it

Comment: @NickBrown The consensus here is to provide self-contained answers, not link-only ones which need readers to go elsewhere.

Comment: @NickBrown Since 5e is not open material, there is no such place with all official items available. The 5e SRD only has a subset.

Comment: If you can legitimately copy this from 5e SRD or dndbeyond, then this should be fine.  I assumed (based on citation) that this was copied directly from the DMG and might exceed fair use.

Comment: @NickBrown Still, linking to any Wizards Official source has it's demerits. I cite the example of Wizards deleting their community forums: https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5931/how-should-all-the-broken-links-to-wizards-forums-be-handled

Comment: I think your copyright enforcement enthusiasm has been overbroad here; it's pretty important to know that equipping the Hand of Vecna has some very big drawbacks.

Answer (score 6):

Nothing stops you from creating your own. Pick a ring/amulet/rock/whatever fits, decide on the regeneration effect, give it a catchy name, and you're set. I would suggest adding some penalty (cosmetic or otherwise) like perhaps a cool-down period, or the inability to sleep for 24 hours, or whatever, just to deter the player from becoming (or believing they've become) bulletproof.

Comment: That's good... I like that. Not gonna give it answer, but makes my mind wander... Thanks for the thought. Definite +1

Comment: Apparently OP was asking as a player, not the DM.