# Can magic missile be used to propel objects?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, combat

Magic missile is a force type and other force types spells typically involve some kind of physical manifestation. 
See:

- Blade Barrier → force weapons
- Clenched Fist → big, punching hand
- Crushing Hand → big hand squeezing
- Mage’s Sword → force weapon
- Explosive Runes → explosion
- Magic Missile → force projectiles
- Spiritual weapon → force weapon

To factor the amount of push, I was thinking that we could look at the force involved with fall damage. The players handbook states different fall damages as equating to 1d6 damage at given weights.

This chart is from dnd 3.5e PHB on fall damage.
$$
\begin{array}{l|r}
Distance   & Weight \\
\hline
10  & 201 \\
20  & 101 \\
30  &  51 \\
40  &  31 \\
50  &  11 \\
60  &   6 \\
70  &   1 \\
100 &   ? \\
\end{array}
$$

That being said, magic missile when empowered is roughly 1d6 + 1 damage after the multiplier is added at 100 ft minimum range. Applying different regressions to the pattern above, we come up with some possible values for the force of incredibly small things such as bullets or pellets. The negatives might make sense for magic missile if you think of it as being a gravity based attack.

These are just mathematic regressions using the fall damage chart.

- Using Quadratic Regression: \$X = -45.784\$
- Using Exponential Regression: \$X = -10.812\$
- Using Logarithmic Regression: \$X = .127\$

A bullet or pellet typically weighs less than .127 pounds. 
You can look [here](http://www.survivalistboards.com/showthread.php?t=159381) for example real world weights in pounds.

With that being said, you could fill the chamber of a cannon or gun or even blow dart chamber with potentially anything and have the magic missile burst that shrapnel towards the target. Note that magic missile never misses.

I could understand if the magic missile having a 100% hit doesn't equate to the projectiles having the same, though if the magic missile acts as a continuous pusher, it could apply? The projectiles would be "in the way" of the magic missile which is comprised of force damage.

So, is this actually feasible?

Comment: Is the *Player's Handbook* here the *Pathfinder Core Rulebook*? Could this question link to or cite the first chart? I think the core idea here is using the spell *magic missile* as propulsion for the cannon's actual load, but I'm struggling a bit—can you confirm that's accurate?

Comment: I agree with HeyICanChan, looking at the environmental fall damage rules Im not seeing the chart you have listed. Part of me wonders if you are using an old copy of the manual, or one from a different game.

Comment: @Fering True. The max damage from the dice roll become 1.5 to 6 + 1 range instead of 1 to 6 + 1 range.

Comment: @HeyICanChan The chart came from http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Falling . Though, it does leave it unambiguois as to which SRD source is used.

Comment: Would anyone be opposed if I changed this to dnd 3.5e instead of pathfinder?

Comment: Can we get some labels or an explanation for the chart at the top? Right now it's just random numbers in columns.

Comment: @HeyICanChan I specifically intended this question to be about magic missile usage.

Comment: The question should be posed so that answers help *you.* If you're playing in a *3.5e* campaign where your PC is considering building such a contraption, ask about *3.5e*, and if playing *Pathfinder*, ask about that. If this, instead, is a question about the *magic missile* spell, please, ask *specifically* about that: *Can the* magic missile *spell be used to propel projectiles?* then explain what you plan to do with that information.

Comment: @Fering Please don’t answer in comments. See [this FAQ](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6533/321) for why your comments were removed.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Which one was considered a partial answer?

Comment: @Fering Neither were attempting to help improve the question, both were attempting to engage with the ideas in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The spell [*magic missile*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsMtoO.html#magic-missile) [targets](http://dndsrd.net/magicOverview.html#target-or-targets) only creatures

A caster can't propel projectiles with the 1st-level Sor/Wiz spell *magic missile* [evoc] (*Player's Handbook* 251) anymore than a caster can knock over a statue with a *magic missile* spell.

The spell *magic missile* has the entry *Targets: Up to five creatures, no two of which can be more than 15 ft. apart.* (Also see [Aiming a Spell](http://dndsrd.net/magicOverview.html#aiming-a-spell) on [Target or Targets](http://dndsrd.net/magicOverview.html#target-or-targets) on *PH* 175.) That target entry means that if a pile of rocks is between the caster and the *magic missile* spell's target, and the caster still has line of sight and line of effect to the target, the target is dealt damage by the *magic missile* spell and the pile of rocks unaffected. On the other hand, if the pile of rocks is big enough that it blocks the caster's line of sight or line of effect to the spell's intended target, the *magic missile* spell's missile fails. There's simply no *third* option for the typical caster to have his *magic missile* spell's missile, for example, *topple* the pile of rocks then *continue* toward the target.

In the same way, experimenting with a magic item that has a *magic missile* effect created *behind* shrapnel should ***either*** see the *magic missile* effect speed normally toward the designated target yet leave the shrapnel untouched ***or*** see the *magic missile* effect fail because the effect's line of sight or effect or both is blocked.

I'm not trying to be a wet blanket here, by the way. I don't, like, have an agenda that says, "Oho, *magic missile*! No way, bub!" or anything. The spell *magic missile* just isn't, technically, the right tool for the job. For example, the 5th-level Sor/Wiz spell [*telekinesis*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsTtoZ.html#telekinesis) [trans] (*PH* 292) is better, as is the 0-level spell *launch item* [trans] (*Spell Compendium* 130-1) and the 1st-level Sor/Wiz spell *scatterspray* [trans] (*SpC* 180). A player that came to this DM with the idea the question proposes would see this DM recommend one of *those* spells as the prerequisite for creating a magic cannon instead of the spell *magic missile*.

### "What if the DM says *magic missile* works anyway?"

[If a PC has gone to all the trouble of researching an original magic item that works this way, and the DM has approved the magic item](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/104123/8610), then that magic item totally works this way, and *it doesn't matter* if the spell's description or other rules *are* to the contrary! Original magic items work however the DM says they work, regardless of if the underlying principle is rooted in the game's mechanics. In such a case, have fun blowing up foes—*and* their fortifications!—with your *magic missile*-powered cannon!

Comment: Very well worded.