# Command activated items of negative energy ray or Repair light damage

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items

A command activated item costs caster level X spell level X 1800 (for an instantaneous spell).

So imagine this: A belt or something of negative energy ray (caster lvl 1, spell lvl 1 x 1800=1800) and a caster with tomb tainted soul allowing him to use the ray to heal himself as a standard action.

Or a construct (intelligent item) with a command activated item of repair light damage (caster lvl 1, spell level 1 x 1800=1800), once again this creature can heal itself as a standard action.

But looking at a spell like cure light wounds, there is no way you would make an item of cure light wounds as command activated costing only 1800.

So I suppose my question is balance based. It is obvious to me that an item that can cure just about anyone for only 1800 is out of the question, but an item that can heal because you took a feat or because of your creature type I could reasonably see costing 1800 as standard actions are precious in combat.

Comment: Just to be clear: As the DM, you're wondering if it would be unbalanced to introduce this magic item to the campaign? Have you read [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/37284/8610)? (I'd also like to point you back to [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/104123/8610) about making custom magic items that's in response to one of your questions back in July.)

Comment: I’m going to say that this is a duplicate of the *cure light wounds* button one; the switch to *repair light damage* or *negative energy ray* (plus Tomb-Tainted Soul) doesn’t really change matters much, the question is still about the balance of indefinite healing.

Comment: Correct I am a dm concerned on balancing and I agree, I guess the reason I wonder on the negative energy ray is that it is really meant for offense (and is poor at that to begin with) and if a character doesn't have the mob tainted soul feat presents no balancing issues.

Comment: So is the broader question *Should the DM change the estimated or listed price of a magic item based on the presence of a particular game feature (like a feat or a prestige class) in the campaign?* Because that's a valid question, and it should stand alone. (Although I suggest trying to find a different example from this one because, like KRyan says, as it stands if this item is your only concern, those are addressed by the other question.)

Comment: To clarify, would you consider the negative energy ray item to be a good example? My thinking is, in a campaign without the tomb tainted soul feat it is perfectly viable, but it comes into question if the feat is available. Thoughts?

Comment: I think the *negative energy ray* item would work as *an* example, but it shouldn't be the *only* example else the question'll just get marked as a duplicate again. Additional examples may include things like making a *water breathing* magic item cheaper because there's an aquatic elf PC or making *wings of flying* cheaper because all the PCs are  raptorans or some other flying race or whatever. (Note that this DM would still mandate making a *wand* or *eternal wand of negative energy ray* rather than a new wondrous item if all the wondrous item's gonna do is cast that spell over and over.)